Issue where logfile is not created when running dmalloc
ubuntu ver : 20.04
gcc ver : gcc (Ubuntu 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.5.0
target : jetson board (aarch64 architecture)
system info. : 5.10.104-tegra
hello.
I have a question regarding the use of dmalloc.
The desired task is to compile the test.c source code and check memory usage(or memory leakage) using dmalloc. At this time, the dmalloc-related git clone process I applied is explained as follows.

git clone https://github.com/j256/dmalloc.git
./configure
make && make install


dmalloc settings

dmalloc -l ./logfile -i 100 high > dmalloc_setup (or dmalloc -l /home/jetson/profile_test1/dmalloc/logfile -i 100 high > dmalloc_setup)
source dmalloc_setup
echo $DMALLOC_OPTIONS


run

gcc -g -DDMALLOC -o test test.c -ldmalloc
./test
cat logfile



The code in my test.c is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef DMALLOC
#include <dmalloc.h>
#endif

int main() {
   char *ch_p = (char *)malloc(10);

  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      malloc(100);            // no free

  calloc(16, 16);             // no free
  return 0;
}

But, at this time, the logfile is not created. Any problem?
